# Unexpected error when refencing an F# project from a C# project

Tags: c#, f#, .net-4.8

The following 3 .net projects

P2.fsproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>
      <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class2.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NinjaTrader.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\NinjaTrader 8\bin\NinjaTrader.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="7.0.400-beta.23251.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

P3.csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
      <TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
      <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
      <RootNamespace>HF</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Class3.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NinjaTrader.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\NinjaTrader 8\bin\NinjaTrader.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

P1.csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NinjaTrader.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\NinjaTrader 8\bin\NinjaTrader.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\P2\P2.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\P3\P3.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

have a single source code file, respectively

Class2.fs

```
namespace P2

open NinjaTrader.NinjaScript

type Class2(host: IndicatorBase) = class end
```

Class3.cs

```
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript;

namespace P3 {
    public class Class3 {
        IndicatorBase _host;

        public Class3(IndicatorBase host)
        {
            _host = host;
        }
    }
}
```

Class1.cs

```
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript;

namespace P1 {
    internal class Class1 : IndicatorBase {
        P2.Class2 _c2;
        P3.Class3 _c3;

        public Class1()
        {
            _c2 = new P2.Class2(this);
            _c3 = new P3.Class3(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that:

- All the 3 project reference a local DLL NinjaTrader.Core.dll (where the type IndicatorBase is defined)
- P2 and P3 both define a single class with identical shape (different names and language)
- P1 references both P2 and P3

Visual studio complains on the instantiation of Class2 in Class1, but not on Class3; the error is

> Error CS0012  The type 'IndicatorBase' is defined in an assembly that
> is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
> 'NinjaTrader.Core, Version=8.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=0907d8af90186095'. P1  C:\Temp\Ninja\Test1\Solution1\P1\Class1.cs  10  Active

Can someone figure out the issue?

[image]

Comment: There are 7 `..`s in ``..\..\..\..\..\..\..\``, but only 5 folders in ``C:\Temp\Ninja\Test1\Solution1\P1\``. You can add the reference dll in Visual Studio.

Comment: @shingo Reference updated.. obviously that is not the reason, issue is still there.